# Задача с нахождением высоты

Tags: c++, геометрия

Школьная задача C++, решить не могу, подскажите в чем ошибка или просто намекните как по другому ее решать?

**Задача:** Вокруг планеты, радиус которой r, обвязана веревка. Веревка была удлинена на 100 метров и на каждой точке поднялась на одинаковое расстояние. На сколько метров поднялась веревка? (Вместо числа ПИ используйте дробь 355/113).

**Ввод:** целое число r (1 ≤ r ≤ 10666666666).

**Вывод:** Вывести высоту (оставив 3 цифры после запятой).

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

*код:*

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
long double r, l1, l2, pal=100;
double pi=3.14159292035, zz=39.479;
cin>>r;

l1=2*pi*r;
l2=2*pi*(r+pal);

cout<<fixed<<setprecision(3)<<(l2-l1)/zz<<endl;
return 0;
}
```

Comment: А у вас какие-нибудь ошибки выбивает или вычисления не верные?

Comment: Если, что вместо ПИ я пробовал использовать и "3.14159292035" и дробь "355/113", разницы нету, ошибка не в этом.

Comment: @Tivyram вычисления не верные

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Скажите, а зачем вам вообще эти мучения? С переводами целых чисел в дробные и проблемами переполнения? Да еще и с вычислениями не того, что сказано в задаче?

```
cout << "15.915\n";
```

вполне достаточно - ответ ведь от радиуса не зависит...

Comment: но ведь надо, чтобы можно было любой радиус ввести, не только 200

Comment: Ну пусть вводят, вам-то что? Что, кто-то проверяет, считан он или нет? :)

Comment: Мне ее школьный учитель дал. Можете еще раз пояснить, какой бы радиус мы не ввели, ответ будет всегда одинаковый? В чем смысл такой задачи тогда? Неужели нету никаких подводных камней?

Comment: ладно в любом случае спасибо, не буду тогда тратить время на нее :)

Comment: 2*pi*(r+h) - 2*pi*r = 100, откуда h = 50/pi. Собственно, все. Это и есть главный подводный камень - правильно написать уравнение и понять, что от r ничего не зависит...

Comment: наконец понял, спасибо еще раз